# interchanging the variables in the equation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, coordinate-systems

I am given the following equation
         $$y=7.515x^3-10.229x^2+5.05x$$
How do I find the value of $x$ when $y$ is given. I need to somehow interchange the position of $x$ and $y$ so that the equation has only $x$ on left side of equality.

Comment: The equation gives you a function in $x$. There is no way to interchange the variables in this equation as $y$ might not necessarily follow the constraints obtained by interchanging the variables.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial function $f(x) =7.515 x^3 - 10.229 x^2 + 5.05 x$ has the derivative
$f'(x) = 22.545 x^2 - 20.458 x + 5.05$, which is positive for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with a local minimum at $x_m=20.458/45.090$ with $f'(x_m) \approx 0.887451$.

Therefore the inverse function $f^{-1} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is well-defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$ So to get $x$ given $y$ you have to compute $x = f^{-1}(y)$, i.e. compute **the** real root of the [cubic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Roots_of_a_cubic_function)
$$7.515 x^3 - 10.229 x^2 + 5.05 x - y = 0.$$
This can be done with the formulas given in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Roots_of_a_cubic_function) or with a 
[root-finding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_finding) like Newton's method or with bisection.